# Regexp_replace : Remove dupliactes from '+' dilimited string in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string in a table column delimited by '+'. I need to remove the duplicates.

Illustration :

My data:

```
a+a+a+b+b+c+c
```

Expectation:

```
a+b+c
```

I tried with `REGEXP_REPLACE` but not able to escape the `+` character as it is reserved.

I am successful with `comma` separated value but need help with `+` or `?` separated values.

Working Code with `comma` separated value:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('a,a,a,b,b,c,c', '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: have you tried escaping +? like :   ('a+a+a+b+b+c+c', '([^\+]+)(+\1)+', '\1')

Comment: @marco You forgot a comma : `([^\+]+)(\+\1)+`

Comment: thanks Paul, I have corrected

Comment: working .. Thanks :)

Comment: pls mark as resolved for future users

Comment: Fix your data structure.  You shouldn't be storing lists as strings, especially when Oracle offers many alternatives.

Comment: This regular expression does not work when the repeating items are not consecutive. It also does not work if you have `ba+a` as it will match the `a` in `ba` and remove the unique `a` term that should be kept.

Comment: @MT0 : That's a good point.. Thanks. but the solution works fine for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a reserved character as its normal value you need to escape it with a backslash. This works for all reserved characters.

```
\
```

You can modify your existing code by replacing each comma in the regex with...

```
\+
```

For example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a+a+a+b+b+c+c', '([^\+]+)(\+\1)+', '\1') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What about `a+b+a+b+c+b+a+c`? or `ba+a`?

Answer (score 0):

just escape the +:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('a+a+a+b+b+c+c', '([^\+]+)(\+\1)+', '\1') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: You need to use back-slash, not forward-slash to escape